# How to get tool-readable XMI with Atlas Transformation Language

Tags: uml, transformation, m2m, xmi, metamodel

I'm a beginner with Atlas Transformation Language and have already made some steps with transforming models based on severeal meta-models. Now I want to transform a specified model based on metamodel1 to a uml-model based on the uml-metamodel. The problem I have is that I want get a xmi-file which I could read with my uml-tool (it's Magic Draw).
Where can I get a uml-metamodel which I could use in ATL to produce machine readable xmi-files. All my current approaches weren't successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is not ATL. Whether the XMI file you get is readable by MagicDraw depends on the UML metamodel you use as a target for the transformation.

An ATL transformation generates models, how these models are stored as XMI files does not depend on ATL but on the metamodel of the target model.

You should first check whether MagicDraw can read UML models created with any of the available Eclipse UML tools and if so, then you can use that metamodel when preparing your transformation